# UITableView crashes because of Late API response

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm new to the swift.

I have 4 tabs on the top and a tableview under it. On clicking each tabs, an API call is made and populated the table view with the data.But if I clicking the tabs really fast even before the API response comes frequently, the app crashes.

It shows different issues.
sometimes,

- Array index out of range
- [UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).
- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

What will be the problem? I'm calling the API, deleting the old array data and parse new data into it and calling `tableview.reload()` method in the main thread. please help me.

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is to make 4 different UITableView and switch them according to your tab selection.

Comment: @andykkt ,thanks for the reply. i have added different table view for each tab selection. even if, if im clicking on a particular tab fastly for number of time, its now giving array index out of bound. I think it is because  im deleting the array within the API call during table reloading is occcuring. How can i handle this situvation? Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a problem in wrong multithreading concept. In your current implementation if you switch tabs fast you may come into situation when you are on one tab and one of previous API requests finishes. So you will have table view populated by wrong data from another tab. To avoid these you may choose one of the following:

1. When you switch to a tab, cancel all of the previous requests.
2. Somehow map result of request to appropriate tabs and update table view only if request corresponds to currently selected tab.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have added different table view for each tab selection. even if, if im clicking on a particular tab fastly for number of time, its now giving array index out of bound. I think it is because im deleting the array within the API call during table reloading is occcuring. How can i handle this situvation? Please suggest me